# Invoking present on modal view — nothing shows, despite debug output shows that they do load

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

Trying to present a `ModalView` from my "`ParentViewController`" but nothing shows in the simulator

- **`ParentViewController.swift`** (really the only code except for boilerplate UIViewController code) looks like so:

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
       modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
       present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```
- My storyboard has the following set:

  - **`ParentViewController`**

    - `Defines Context` = True
    - `Provides Context` = True
  - **`Segue`**

    - `Kind`: Presents modally
    - `Presentation`: Over current context
  - **`ModalViewController`**

    - `Presentation`: Over current context
- Debug print statements from `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` in `ModalViewController.swift` shows that these at least seem to be executed.

Comment: I've just checked this code. Everything's ok. Seems there's something else

Comment: What type of ModalViewController() ? maybe it's presented, but u can't see anything. Try to set Background color to its view. 
In ModalViewController class, set self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably lie in this

```
let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
```

You are creating an instance of ViewController without its view, so its blank, thats why you see nothing on screen, if your ViewController is from storyboard, you have to use something like `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ModalViewController")`, if its from code, have to put the construct code in it's `loadView()`